# PHP MySQL update statement fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Yes, I know there are answers for PHP MySQL update statements, however none of them have yet to solve the issue.  My reset PHP file prepares the query just fine using bind_param or concatenated variables.  It also executes fine as it redirects to the reset_success page.  The database record however, goes unchanged.  I have confirmed that the user the website is using has update privileges.  I have even tried escaping `password` as it is a lowercase version of a reserve word, nothing has worked.  The apache2 error log also shows no errors, so no help there.

The code is as follows:

```
if (empty($error_msg)) {

    // Create a random salt
    $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

    // Create salted password 
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

    // Prepare the update statement
    //if ($update_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET password = ?, salt = ? WHERE email = ?")) {
    if ($update_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET password = '".$password."', salt = '".$random_salt."' WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['email']."';")) {

        // Binding params
        //$update_stmt->bind_param('sss', $password, $random_salt, $_SESSION['email']);

        // Execute the update statement
        if ($update_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: reset_success.php');
            exit();
        }
        else{
            header('Location: error.php?err=Reset failure: UPDATE');
            exit();
        }

    }
    else{
        header('Location: error.php?err=Reset failure: PREPARE');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You shoul look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). It's much less of a hassle than escaping, and the resulting code will protect you against SQL injections too.

Comment: I thought that is what i was doing with the $mysqli->prepare?

Comment: Could you please ensure `$_SESSION['email']` holds the correct value ?

Comment: But you're using string replacements to set the values instead of bind variables, making this a bit useles.

Comment: The binding part (`bind_param()`), which you have disabled, is the part that sanitizes the variable to be binded in your query.

Comment: $_SESSION['email'] echo's to the correct value, and sorry I left out the top I am sanitizing using filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'answer', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); and the same for password.

Comment: You should also use back tick character (\`) with the reserved keywords while using them in query. eg. \`password\`

Comment: I tried that also, it did not make any difference.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try a commit() before switching to reset_success ?

Comment: Yes, I just tried a commit() and it didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is working.  I needed an additional call to session_start() in the function file even though the reset_password.php does not redirect ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']). This was NOT needed in for the registration page and its corresponding function file which operates in the same manner.  I'm still unclear as to why that is needed again when the referrer is itself and is not redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long.

> $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

This very wrong. You are padding the salt from 16 to 64 bits **and** removing the entropy by hashing it. If you want 64 random bytes then just use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64).

> The apache2 error log also shows no errors

Have you checked that PHP error logging is working?

Why didn't you check the mysql logs?

> if ($update_stmt->execute()) {

Try checking $update_stmt->affected_rows()

Comment: Thank you for the great information about the hashing.  The apache2 error loggin is working, I'm not sure that MySQL logging is.  On debian I read that it should be left as the system logging default but nothing shows under /var/log/mysql/error.log.  I don't have enough rep to upvote you yet...